# SQLite text date is giving me an error that doesn't make sense

Tags: sql, date, datetime, sqlite

I'm trying to create a table in SQLite that holds a date. I looked on their site and see that I have to use text to store it. However, I'm getting an error that I think it from me not inserting the data value correctly.

```sql
CREATE TABLE fitness_data(
  user varchar(20) primary key,
  day text,
  steps int,
  minOfExercise int,
  calories int
  );

INSERT INTO fitness_data('wrkey', '2019-04-15', 5873, 47, 1429);
Error: near "5873": syntax error
```

I'm not sure why it won't let me insert the data. I realize that the error is at the steps int, but I think it has something to do with the date as I've never worked with that before and I don't see an issue with my steps value.

Anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html and/or a good SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for the [INSERT INTO](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) statement is:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ....)
```

so when you execute this:

```
INSERT INTO fitness_data('wrkey', '2019-04-15', 5873, 47, 1429)
```

then `'wrkey'`, `'2019-04-15'`, `5873`, `47`, `1429` are considered as column names and not the values that you want to insert. 
You can solve this by using the `VALUES` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO fitness_data VALUES ('wrkey', '2019-04-15', 5873, 47, 1429)
```

since you set values to all the columns,
but in general it's always a good practice to include in your statement all the column names for which you want to set a value:

```
INSERT INTO fitness_data 
  (user, day text, steps, minOfExercise, calories)
  VALUES 
  ('wrkey', '2019-04-15', 5873, 47, 1429)
```

Comment: Didn't realize I forgot the values keyword. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO fitness_data (user_key, day, steps, minOfExercise, calories) VALUES ('wrkey', '2019-04-15', 5873, 47, 1429);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. I didn't even realize I wasn't using the values keyword. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO fitness_data VALUES ('wrkey', '2019-04-15', 5873, 47, 1429);
```

Although the preferred way is always list the fields you're inserting into:

```
INSERT INTO fitness_data (user, day, steps, minOfExercise, calories) values ('wrkey', '2019-04-15', 5873, 47, 1429);
```

Comment: I forgot the values keyword... Oops. Thanks!